# Why is my responsive menu button not working?

Tags: javascript, css

My responsive menu is not being displayed upon pressing the button

I have a simple icon, and the plan is that upon being pressed, it should display the menu of my website.

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
```

I have set the original display of my navbar to none, and when i press the button, the active class is given to the navbar, and it should display block,but the menu is not showing up.

Here's the relevant css:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    #darkMode-icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 7rem;
        font-size: 2.6rem;
        color: var(--text-color);
        margin-bottom: .1rem;
    }

    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1rem 3%;
        background: var(--bg-color);
        border-top: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar .active {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar a {
        display: block;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 3rem 0;
        color: var(--text-color);
    }

    .navbar a:nth-child(1),
    .navbar a:nth-child(2) {
        color: var(--text-color);
    }

    .navbar a.active {
        color: var(--main-color);
    }

    .navbar a::before {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Here's the JS i used:

```js
let menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

menuIcon.onclick = () => {
  menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
  navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};
```

I checked, and the active class is given to the navbar when i click the button and it's also being removed correctly. The bx-x class is also given to my menu icon, which turns it into an X. This function works, because the icon does actually turn into an X, so the JS should be fine, but the menu is not showing up.

Comment: Unfortunately the described behaviour is not reproducible as you didn't provide a complete code example. Please spice-up your question with some code that clearly show-cases the issue you're having.

Comment: there is a space in the selector `.navbar .active` remove the space to select a navbar that also have an active class